# Detect if a network card is a virtual network card (docker/veth/etc) in Linux / bsd

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtual-network

I see some good explanation for fetching information about network cards and their statistics in ubuntu on [this](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man3/getifaddrs.3.html) page. This gave a nice output as mentioned on the page. I tried reading other documentations too but could not find a flag or something similar where I can differentiate between the real and virtual network cards on my system.

Is there are way to differentiate ? 
Thanks.

Comment: Note that for HVM devices there may be no way of telling as hypervisors emulate a real device (usually Intel or Realtek).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the `/sys/class/net/<device_name>` symlink. If it points into `/sys/devices/virtual/`, then it is a virtual interface. If it points to a "real" device (e.g. into `/sys/devices/pci0000:00/`), then it is not.

**Edit:**

From code, you can use `readlink` to check if the device is virtual. Here is a very dummy sample code to do so:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char theLink[128];
    char thePath[128];

    strcpy(thePath,"/sys/class/net/");
    memset(theLink,0,128);

    if (argc>1) {
        strcat(thePath,argv[1]);
    } else {
        printf("Gimme device\n");
        return 1;
    }

    if (readlink(thePath, theLink, 127)==-1) {
        perror(argv[1]);
    } else {
        if (strstr(theLink,"/virtual")) {
            printf("%s is a virtual device\n",argv[1]);
        } else {
            printf("%s is a physical device\n",argv[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sounds promising, anything similar for virtual disks also ? 
And it seems like I need to do `ls -l` for confirming this. Any way from code ?

Comment: For disks, check the symlinks in `/sys/class/block`. Also, I added a primitive sample to check if the device is virtual.

Comment: The sample works excellent for EC2 instances also, for the `/sys/class/block` link, probably I used the wrong word (disk). I need for mount points (/root, /mnt, etc). Is there a local in system for these also ? @Lacek

Comment: I think mount points can only be extracted from `/proc/mounts` (on Linux, this is a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`). Parsing that file is a bit more difficult though.

Comment: @Gagan93: What do you mean by virtual mount points? Every since the big VFS re-write ~20 years ago, I don't think that makes much sense. The current Linux VFS is very Plan9-like where everything is a (potential) file system, everything is a (potential) mount point, and every mount point is (in some sense) virtual.

Comment: Why have you written a C program? Why not `readlink /path/to/device && ... || ...` or whatever in (ba)sh?

Comment: @cat : There is an existing C binary doing some operations so I am planning to add this logic to exclude virtual network cards.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is to check if the file `/sys/class/net/<interface>/device` exists. Usually docker and other virtual interfaces doesn't have that file (which is actually a symlink to the device). This should work:

```bash
for device in $(ls /sys/class/net/); do
  if [ -L /sys/class/net/$device/device ]; then
     echo "Device : $device"
  else
     echo "Virtual: $device"
  fi
done
```

Output (example executed in my laptop):

```
Virtual: docker0
Virtual: docker_gwbridge
Device : enp0s25
Virtual: lo
Virtual: veth7a67a62
Device : wlo1
Virtual: ztmjfg2jdx
```

Tested in `Ubuntu 22.04` not sure if the same applies to other distributions.